# How to access environment variables in C#'s .config files on MacOS?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, environment-variables, app-config

I am not able to access environment variables in C# console application's app.config file.

I want to access log-level's value from ENVIRONMENT Variable `LOG_LEVEL` in app.config :

```
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <root>
          <level value="INFO"/>
          <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </root>
        <!--log to console-->
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
          </layout>
        </appender>
     </log4net>
  </configuration>
```

I want to access it like `<level value=%LOG_LEVEL%>`.

But I am not able to access it on OSX. 
I have tried using it like `$LOG_LEVEL`,  `${LOG_LEVEL}` , `%LOG_LEVEL`

Comment: by showing your code people will have a much better chance of understanding what you are asking

Comment: Have you tried `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("log4net")`?

Comment: @RicardoPontual .. I know, I can always do this by accessing config section in code and access Environment variable by method `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG_LEVEL")`.

Comment: @Seabizkit.. Right now, I am setting in value of level in code only and I am able to do this. 
But I want to do it in .config file. As I feel that setting such value via code is not best practice.

Comment: There is no environment variable substitution at the .NET config level. So this is really a log4net question. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600147/is-it-possible-to-use-environment-variable-to-specify-the-desired-log-level-for the answer was “you can’t” 8 years ago.

Comment: @Zastai .. Thanks but this answer suggests opposite : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303113/app-config-settings-environment-variable-as-partial-path

Comment: To me, that answer still says you have to do it in code, but if you use the `%VarName%` notation, you only need a single method call. If it’s log4net reading that setting, chances are it won’t do that. And doing it in code is what I thought you didn’t want.